# run cypress tests from command line getting => CypressError: Cypress test was stopped while running this command

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-configuration

Cypress version 10.3.0

I have a following test.cy.js, which is async IT block.

///

```
import loadFileObjects from '../../../support/load_file_objects'
var fixtureUrl = '/test/mydata/'

describe("TC1_getResidentialInfo", () => {
    var load_test_case;
    it('Validate and load all automation feeds', async () => {
        load_test_case = await loadFileObjects.getJsonObj(fixtureUrl + '/CUP-575-TC1-TC.json');
        })
})
```

support/load_file_objects.js

```
class load_file_objects{
        //it should accept fixture folder structure and test case name
        //returns json object directly using promise
     getJsonObj(testCasePath){
        // return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                cy.fixture(testCasePath).then((data) => {
                    cy.log("Test Data for "+testCasePath+ ": " +JSON.stringify(data))
                    resolve(data)
                })
                // do something custom here
              })
            
            //  var data = data;
            //  return data
        // })
    }
}
export default load_file_objects
```

Its working fine when I run the same test using cypress open(Test runner UI)
Please let me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class instance needs to be created somewhere.

Convention is class names are capitalized. This is the clean way to do it

```js
class LoadFileObjects {
  ...
export default LoadFileObjects
```

or

```js
import LoadFileObjects from '../../../support/load_file_objects'

it('Validate and load all automation feeds', async () => {

  const loadFileObjects = new LoadFileObjects()
  const load_test_case = await loadFileObjects.getJsonObj(fixtureUrl + '/CUP-575-TC1-TC.json');
})
```

---

**Requiring the fixture**

If the path to your fixture file is fixed and consistent, then you can use `require()` at the top of the script to do the async/await heavy lifting for you.

```js
const load_test_case = require('./cypress/fixtures/test/mydata/CUP-575-TC1-TC.json')
```

Comment: Thanks @Fody, Checked with that as well, Issue is with async and await. Still getting the same error.

Comment: The way you laid out the code looks ok, will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Following ERROR:  
Validate and load all automation feeds for :
     CypressError: Cypress test was stopped while running this command.
      at cypressErr (http://localhost:61412/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:174984:18)
      at Object.errByPath (http://localhost:61412/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175053:10)
      at http://localhost:61412/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:176846:80

Comment: It may be possible to import the fixture directly - see addition above.

Comment: I ran your code `support/load_file_objects.js` with the test version I gave above and it works fine. Only thing I had to do was modify the import path to `import LoadFileObjects from '../support/load_file_objects'`. My test is in `/cypress/e2e` folder.

Comment: Can we add multiple await inside one async function (it block)?